# How to format a php array into a javascript array?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a `3D array` in `php` when using `var_dump($arr)` it looks like this

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> array(4) { 
  [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "36.3636" [1]=> int(8) } 
  [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "27.2727" [1]=> int(5) } 
  [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "36.3636" [1]=> int(2) } 
  [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "28.5714" [1]=> int(10) } 
} 

[1]=> array(3) { 
   [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "18.1818" [1]=> int(10) } 
   [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "18.1818" [1]=> int(9) } 
   [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "0.0000" [1]=> int(6) } 
} 


}
```

I want to get it in this format in javascript:

```
var data = [
                [
                  {x:36, y:8, r:10},{x:27, y:5, r:10},{x:36, y:2, r:10},{x:28, y:10, r:10}
                ],
                [
                  {x:18, y:10, r:10},{x:18, y:9, r:10},{x:0, y:6, r:10}
                ]
            ];
```

Where `x` is the `[0] index` of innermost array and `y` is `[1] index` of innermost array `r` is always `10`

How do i format it in this way ?

Comment: You can loop through the array and process data, generate a string and then echo that string,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could format the data then echo the result as a javascript variable.

```
<?php

$data = [
  [
    [ "36.3636", 8 ],
    [ "27.2727", 5 ],
    [ "36.3636", 2 ],
    [ "28.5714", 10 ],
  ],
  [
    [ "18.1818", 10 ],
    [ "18.1818", 9 ],
    [ "0.0000", 6 ],
  ]
];

// reformat the data in php to your desired format
$formatted = array_map(function($coords) {
  return array_map(function($item) {
    return [
      'x' => (int) $item[0],
      'y' => (int) $item[1],
      'r' => 10,
    ];
  }, $coords);
}, $data);

?>
<!-- echo json encode your formatted data as a javascript variable -->
<script>var data = <?=json_encode($formatted, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)?>;</script>
<script>console.log(data)</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo  json_encode($arr);
```

or if you are building your json string manually make sure to use the following in your front JS:

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: Other way around, you would `json_decode` a json string that you received from a http request. to print to javascript you would `json_encode` the php array.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will definitely work

```
<?php echo json_encode($array) ?>
```